# Order of execution for arguments in console.log()

Tags: javascript, console

I noticed this behavior in CodeAcademy's editor and Chrome's console. Why is the argument of `console.log()` not evaluated first if it is an expression?

```
var x = 0;
console.log(x++);  // prints 0 and not 1
console.log(x);  // prints 1
```

Comment: x++ is a post-increment operation. The variable is used and **then** incremented. If you want it incremented first, use pre-increment with `++x` instead.

Comment: In other words, this has nothing to do with `console.log()` and everything to do with how the `++` operator works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x++` means use the value of `x` then increment it, so the console will log `0` and then `x` will be incremented. If you want to increment `x` before using its value, then use a prefix `++` like this:

```js
var x = 0;

console.log(++x);
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 4):

That is a postfix operator, which means it is not incremented until after the function executes.

You can use the prefix operator: `++x` to modify the value before it prints.